# JQuery Specific Position Detection Scroll Event Question

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner.
No matter how hard I look, I don't know. I leave a question.
I want to make the style added as much as I scroll whenever I scroll to a particular div.

Below is an example homepage.

http://kakaopagecorp.com/

If I touch the bottom footer, I'd like to add a botom and make it come up.

Comment: Please add a code-example to your post.

Answer (score 1):

For example: your div have id: my-div then you can use this code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    let Ptpositon = $(window).scrollTop();
    let mdiv = $("#my-div");
    if (Ptpositon >= mdiv.offset().top - (window.innerHeight/2)){
   //make your magic here:
   // for example: mdiv.css("transform", "translateX(0)");
    }
});
```